# Hotmail put on my emails to Block bounce

Tags: marketing-cloud, bounce-management

The hotmail and others domain are blocking my emails and put on to block bounce?

Either way, what i can do to help my campaigns? It's exclusive by content?

[image]

Comment: Your bouncerates are way to high. You should consider changing something drasticly or you won't reach somebodies inbox soon.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a technical problem, nor an issue from SFMC. This is either a data issue (lots of incorrect emails) or more likely this is a deliverability issue - which is a whole other beast.

Likely you either did not properly warm up your IP, have volume/frequency issues or your authentication (SPF, DKIM, etc) is not up to par for these ISPs.

You should be able to check your domain and IP health here: https://senderscore.org/

Here are a few good links to help you better understand what Deliverability is and some to help you find out how to get off a blacklist.

[Litmus: Deliverability basics](https://litmus.com/community/learning/19-deliverability-basics)
[Campaign Monitor: 9 Things Killing Your Deliverability](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2015/09/9-things-that-are-killing-your-email-deliverability/)

[MailGun: FML I got Blacklisted](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/how-to-get-ip-or-domain-off-email-blacklist)
[BenchMarkEmail: What Should I do if my IP got blacklisted](https://blog.benchmarkemail.com/ip-gets-blacklisted/)

If you don't have the resources to manage it yourself, you should look at 3rd party services, such as [ReturnPath](https://returnpath.com) to help you manage this.

Comment: after your links i noticed that i dont have SSL Certificate and my Email Reply Address is not verified. You think that is there any relationship whith the bounce?

Comment: Yes, I definitely think they are part of the problem, but it sounds like you have a large issue with such high bounce numbers. It would seem that you have likely been blacklisted.